# Is this firebase rule redundant? When to use write vs validate?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I read through [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html), and I'm not sure of the difference between the write-rule and validation-rule section.  Is this code redundant?  Any point of using one or the other, or both?

Specifically:

- "validates" to say "user must be logged in, and the value written must be the uid.
- "write" permission says you can only write to the $user_id section if the value matches your uid.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".validate": "auth != null && newData.val() === auth.uid",
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also confused with them.

Comment: I find a good explaination. See this, https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/validate.html

Answer (score 10):

The **only** difference is that .validate doesn't propagate to its children.

Answering to your question, in your example you could use just ".write".

`".write": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid"`

Comment: Minor thing, but note that .validate is only evaluated if a .write rule granted access.  I would guess that that doesn't make much of a difference, though.

Comment: If something has a value, it doesn't have children, so using .write in every case is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there might not be (except propagation) any difference but in my opinion there is a difference.

For example Security is the primary concern of the `.write` while data integrity is the primary concern of the `.validate`.

For example:

Consider we are writing to `/books/{bookKey}/name` path.

1. Is user allowed to write to this path is `.write`'s concern. Checks like user logged in can be performed here.
2. Is user is entering the right name for the book? Is `.validate`'s concern. For example name should be more than 3 characters long, must start with characters...

P.S.
Also considering [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/308) issue with multi-line, it is good to have two separate methods for more readability.